# How to set up a function pointer parameter so it accepts anything

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers

I'm looking for a way to pass function A() as an argument to function B() in order to calculate the running time of A().

For example:

```
double timer(<passing function A>) {
    clock_t before = clock();

    <calling function A - not caring about what it returns>;

    clock_t after = clock();
    return (double) (before - after) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

My problem is that I have many different functions to test (that does the same job) with different return types and different signatures. I do not know how to correctly set up the  field of the previous example as I'm getting conversion errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use templates:

```
template <typename A>
double timer(const A a) {
   ...

   a();

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.

```
template< class Func >
auto timer( Func const a )
    -> double
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What's with the trailing return type? Anything wrong with good-old `double timer(Func a)`? :)

Comment: @faranwath: what's wrong with the trailing return type? are you suggesting needlessly *mixing* different syntaxes for function declarations?

Comment: I don't quite get you comment. The fact that I'm not a native English speaker might contribute to it, but what do you mean by *mixing different syntaxes for function declarations*?

Comment: @faranwath: The trailing return type syntax is the only one accepted for lambdas, and in practice it's also often necessary for function templates. The old syntax is not needed for anything in pure C++ code (it is necessary for headers that should also be used by a C compiler). As far as I know the only reason for using it in pure C++, and thereby needlessly mixing two different syntaxes (since one can't avoid trailing return type), is purely psychological. Namely, holding on to what one's used to as long as possible, even when it's clearly technically counter-productive.

Comment: I see, but don't you think it could make beginners to freak out and say something along the lines of C++ being a weird language? Nearly every other programming language I've used goes with `type name()`, except the dynamically typed ones (e.g. Lua and Python).

Comment: @faranwath: But C++ *is*  a weird language. Just like the human body is pretty weird. Both resulted from quite haphazard evolution where what worked was generally retained, and what didn't work was scrapped. In the case of C++ that evolution wasn't blind, but still the evolutionary pressure was great: the creator (Bjarne) was not at all free to do what he wanted, and in at least a handful of cases had to accept other ways than he originally wanted. So the language has a lot of idiosyncrasies, both syntax and semantics, but it works. Even though nobody's quite sure why and how. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is wrap your function in a functor and use an instance of the functor to call the timer.

```
template <typename F>
double timer(F f) {
    clock_t before = clock();

    f();

    clock_t after = clock();
    return (double) (before - after) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

int foo(double a)
{
   return (int)(a*a);
}

// foo cannot be used directly as a parameter to timer.
// Construct a functor that wraps around foo.
// An object of FooFunctor can be used as a parameter to timer.
struct FooFunctor
{
   FooFunctor(double a) : a_(a) {}

   void operator(){res_ = foo(a_);}
   double a_;
   int res_;
};

bool bar(double a, double b)
{
   return (a<b);
}

// Similar to foo and FooFunctor.
// Construct a functor that wraps around bar.
// An object of BarFunctor can be used as a parameter to timer.    
struct BarFunctor
{
   BarFunctor(double a, double b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}

   void operator(){res_ = foo(a_, b_);}
   double a_;
   double b_;
   bool res_;
};

void test()
{
   FooFunctor f(10.0);
   std::cout << "Time taken: " << timer(f) << std::endl;

   BarFunctor b(10.0, 20,0);
   std::cout << "Time taken: " << timer(b) << std::endl;
}
```